# Master master replication in mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-replication

i am new in mysql and trying to establish master master replication in mysql

on first server i have added these lines to mysqld section of my.cnf(mysql  Ver 14.12 Distrib 5.0.77, for redhat-linux-gnu (i686) using readline 5.1)

```
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
log-bin=/var/lib/mysql/mysql-bin.log
binlog-do-db=sample1  
binlog-ignore-db=mysql            
binlog-ignore-db=information_schema
binlog-ignore-db=test2
binlog-ignore-db=sample3
binlog-ignore-db=example3
binlog-ignore-db=endpoints
binlog-ignore-db=meetme
binlog-ignore-db=test
binlog-ignore-db=sample2

server-id=1
master-host = 192.xxx.x.xxx
master-user = abc
master-password = abc_pass
master-connect-retry = 60

relay-log = /var/lib/mysql/slave-relay.log
relay-log-index = /var/lib/mysql/slave-relay-log.index
```

On second server i have added these lines to mysqld section of my.cnf(mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.41, for debian-linux-gnu (i486) using readline 6.1)

```
server-id=2

master-host = 192.xxx.x.xxx
master-user = xyz
master-password = xyz_pass
master-connect-retry = 60

relay-log = /var/lib/mysql/slave-relay.log
relay-log-index = /var/lib/mysql/slave-relay-log.index

log-bin = /var/lib/mysql/mysql-bin.log
binlog-do-db = sample1
binlog-ignore-db=mysql
binlog-ignore-db=information_schema
binlog-ignore-db=phpmyadmin
```

on first server slave status is

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
             Slave_IO_State: Connecting to master
                Master_Host: 192.xxx.x.xx
                Master_User: abc
                Master_Port: 3306
              Connect_Retry: 60
            Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000001
        Read_Master_Log_Pos: 36158
             Relay_Log_File: slave-relay.000001
              Relay_Log_Pos: 98
      Relay_Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000001
           Slave_IO_Running: No
          Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
            Replicate_Do_DB: 
        Replicate_Ignore_DB: 
         Replicate_Do_Table: 
     Replicate_Ignore_Table: 
    Replicate_Wild_Do_Table: 
Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table: 
                 Last_Errno: 0
                 Last_Error: 
               Skip_Counter: 0
        Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 36158
            Relay_Log_Space: 98
            Until_Condition: None
             Until_Log_File: 
              Until_Log_Pos: 0
         Master_SSL_Allowed: No
         Master_SSL_CA_File: 
         Master_SSL_CA_Path: 
            Master_SSL_Cert: 
          Master_SSL_Cipher: 
             Master_SSL_Key: 
      Seconds_Behind_Master: NULL
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

ERROR: 
No query specified
```

On second server slave status is

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
               Slave_IO_State: Connecting to master
                  Master_Host: 192.xxx.x.xxx
                  Master_User: xyz
                  Master_Port: 3306
                Connect_Retry: 60
              Master_Log_File: 
          Read_Master_Log_Pos: 4
               Relay_Log_File: slave-relay.000003
                Relay_Log_Pos: 4
        Relay_Master_Log_File: 
             Slave_IO_Running: No
            Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
              Replicate_Do_DB: 
          Replicate_Ignore_DB: 
           Replicate_Do_Table: 
       Replicate_Ignore_Table: 
      Replicate_Wild_Do_Table: 
  Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table: 
                   Last_Errno: 0
                   Last_Error: 
                 Skip_Counter: 5
          Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 0
              Relay_Log_Space: 106
              Until_Condition: None
               Until_Log_File: 
                Until_Log_Pos: 0
           Master_SSL_Allowed: No
           Master_SSL_CA_File: 
           Master_SSL_CA_Path: 
              Master_SSL_Cert: 
            Master_SSL_Cipher: 
               Master_SSL_Key: 
        Seconds_Behind_Master: NULL
Master_SSL_Verify_Server_Cert: No
                Last_IO_Errno: 1045
                Last_IO_Error: error connecting to master 'abc@192.xxx.x.xxx:3306' - retry-time: 60  retries: 86400
               Last_SQL_Errno: 0
               Last_SQL_Error: 
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

ERROR: 
No query specified
```

Do'nt know why Slave_IO_Running is no.

i have tried a lot to start replication but i am still unable to start replication.
i have also commented

```
#bind-address           = 127.0.0.1
```

and

```
#skip-external-locking
```

i need your help. Please send your suggestions and solution for this problem.

Thanks in advance.

regards,
pradeep

Answer (score 1):

Seems that like it's a problem with communication between the two mysql servers. Last_IO_Error: error connecting to master 'abc@192.xxx.x.xxx:3306.

Did you verify that
1)  192.xxx.x.xxx is listening either on 192.xx.x.xxx or 0.0.0.0/0
2) the other server, lets call it 192.xx.x.yyy can connect to it? Determine with mysql, netcat or something

Also seems no master log file nor position was entered. Im sure there are other problems with the configuration, it's very hard reading your configuration and pastes

Answer (score 0):

Did you run [CHANGE MASTER](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/change-master-to.html)?